# If statement being skipped in first cycle of for loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a[3],b[3];
    int sum,sum2;
    int A_poeni = 0, S_poeni = 0;
    int k,l;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
        k = a[i];
        l = b[i];

        //cout << "a[i]: " << a[i] << endl;
        //cout << "b[i]: " << b[i] << endl;
        //cout << "k: " << k << "l: " << l << endl;

        while(k>0)
        {
            sum += k % 10;
            k /= 10;
        }

        sum2=0;

        while(l>0)
        {
            sum2 += l % 10;
            l /= 10;
        }

        //cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;
        //cout << "sum2: " << sum2 << endl;

        if (a[i] % sum == 0)
        {
            cout << "Stefan: " << S_poeni << " " << "Ana: " << A_poeni << endl;
            S_poeni += 2;
            A_poeni -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (b[i] % sum == 0)
        {
            cout << "Stefan: " << S_poeni << " " << "Ana: " << A_poeni << endl;
            S_poeni -= 1;
            A_poeni += 2;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }

    cout << S_poeni << " " << A_poeni << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have to make a program that does the following:

You input numbers x y (100 <=x , y<= 999) where x is number of Stefan and y is number of Ana. You have to check if the number they input, when you divide it by the sum of the digits gives 0, if it does, then x/y gets 2 points and the other player gets -1 point. If the number doesn't meet that, there are no points given/taken to anyone.

Example if number is 110, 1+1+0 = 2, 110%2 = 0, Stefan gets 2 points, Ana gets -1.If number is 890, 8+9+0 = 17, 890%17!=0 no one gets the points.

examples are:

```
101 114
133 360
113 243
```

for input and out put should be:

```
-1 5
Ana
```

my problem is that my "if" statement inside the for loop is being ignore somehow (the first cycle only). I did several tests and I can't find out why...

Comment: `if` isn't a loop statement.

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware of that, just messed up my writing because I wrote it quickly..

Comment: Could you be more specific which of the many `if` statements in the outer loop?

Comment: `if (a[i] % sum == 0)` and `if (b[i] % sum == 0)` are being somehow ignored in the first cycle of the loop.. their values are 0 0 as the default (shouldn't be). the next cycle is ok, and I'm not sure about the last one.

Comment: Did you try stepping through with a debugger and check the values?

Comment: Well, I tried outputting the values before / after each statement and it seems to be skipping the first statement... I don't know about debugger.

Comment: The first `if` is skipped because `(101 % 2) != 0`. This means `else` is executed. Then `continue` is runned (it starts the next iteration of the for loop), so the second `if` is skipped.

Comment: I completely removed the "else" statements and the results are the same as before.

Comment: `if (b[i] % sum == 0)` should be `if (b[i] % sum2 == 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Zifre, the mistake was:

`if (b[i] % sum == 0)`

should be

`if (b[i] % sum2 == 0)`